# Вопрос по поводу иконок для Android.

Tags: android, icon

Я уже полдня ищу качественные иконки для лаунчера 512x512, PNG, но для большинства из найденных требуется лицензия, подскажите, кто где берёт иконки для своих приложений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть 3 варианта:

1. Купить - сайтов таких полно.
2. Заказать у дизайнера на какой-нибудь фриланс-бирже, правда, при этом надо озаботиться отчуждением авторских прав в вашу пользу, иначе потом дизайнер вам может "выкатить" - уже были прецеденты.
3. Скачать со свободной лицензией, например, на [WikiMedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Нарисовать самому не катит: каждый должен заниматься своим делом.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.iconfinder.com/ -  я тут покупал. Недорого вообще. 15-30 рублей одна иконка.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/51152)

Comment: @Suvitruf, даже не знаю, что можно из ссылки сюда вынести. Иконки? По-моему, тут кроме ссылки помочь особо нечем.